# Calculate End Date using Start date

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have three input fields as follows :

```
Warranty Start Date : <input id="WarrantyStartDate"  value="2015-11-22" />
Warranty period : <input id="WarrantyStartDate" value="24"/> //24 months//
Warranty End Date : <input id="WarrantyEndDate" />
```

Now my question is How to calculate the End Date automatically by using the warranty period value..
In Simple I want the Date after 24 months of  this date  "2015-11-22"

I have created a js-fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/3DzTu/14/

SOLVED:

```
function getEndDate(){

var warranty_period = $('#WarrentyPeriod').val();
var warranty_value = parseInt(warranty_period); 

var WarrentyStartDate = $('#WarrentyStartDate').val();
var WarrentyStartDate = WarrentyStartDate.split('-');
var WarrentyStartDate = WarrentyStartDate[0]+'/'+WarrentyStartDate[1]+'/'+WarrentyStartDate[2];
var dateString = WarrentyStartDate; // date string
var actualDate = new Date(dateString); // convert to actual date
var newDate = new Date(actualDate.getFullYear(), actualDate.getMonth()+warranty_value, actualDate.getDate());
var myDate = new Date(newDate);
var myDate = myDate.toLocaleString();
var myDate = myDate.split(',');
var myDate = myDate[0];
var myDate = myDate.split('/');
var year = myDate[2];
var month = '';
var date = '';

if(myDate[0].length < 2){

    month = '0'+myDate[0];
}else{
    month = myDate[0];

}


if(myDate[1].length < 2){

    date = '0'+myDate[1];
}else{
    date = myDate[1];

}

var WarrentyEndDate = year+'-'+month+'-'+date;


 $( "#WarrentyEndDate" ).val(WarrentyEndDate);


}
```

Comment: http://momentjs.com/ is great for manipulating and calculating dates

Comment: `d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + n)` is much simpler than including a library.

Comment: @ajay see sunil's answer. Is there something else that you want?

Comment: I want the Date after 24 month of  this date  "2015-11-22"

Answer (score 3):

```
var d1 = new Date("2015-11-22"); // start date  
var warranty_value = 24; // warranty value
d1.setMonth(d1.getMonth() + warranty_value); // this will give you end date by adding warranty value to start date
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your "Warranty period" has an id of "WarrantyPeriod", you can try the code below:

```
var date = new Date($('#WarrantyStartDate').val());

date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + parseInt($('#WarrantyPeriod').val()));

$("#WarrantyEndDate").val(date.toISOString().slice(0,10));
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var startTime = new Date($("#WarrantyStartDate").datepicker().val()).getTime();
var period = new Date(0).setMonth(24);
var end = new Date(startTime + period);
$("#WarrantyEndDate").datepicker().val(end.getMonth() + "/" + end.getDate() + "/" + end.getFullYear());
```

Comment: var startTime = new Date().getTime();
var period = new Date(0).setMonth(1);
var end = new Date(startTime + period);
alert(end.getDay() + "/" + end.getMonth() + "/" + end.getFullYear());

Comment: it seems to be fault, but month is between 0 - 11
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

*Month*
Integer value representing the month, beginning with 0 for January to 11 for December.